# How (or should I) to connect a D-shaft to a load, through a bearing?

Tags: motors, shafts

I have a gear with a D-shaft that is intended to directly drive a turntable. Something relatively heavy at very low speeds and with not much torque, if it's important.

I really don't want the gear to take the weight of the load, so i want to put a ball bearing between them. So now i am drawing a shaft that comes out of the turntable and goes through the bearing, and has a D-shaped hole in it.

Problem 1: the D-shaped hole requires some fillets as i understand the production - but also small fillet radius is not liked by the manufacturers.

Problem 2: the shaft diameter is 8mm, the bearing bore diameter is 9mm. So that leaves me only 0.5mm thick tube for the D-hole. Seems too thin. Larger bearing is a problem because then i don't know how to mount the motor.

upd. A picture.

[image: parts that i need to connect - not including anything to hold the red shaft or motor]

Comment: Picture > 1000 words.

Comment: it's actually pretty hard to me to make a clear picture. But I'll try

Comment: have you considered using an 8 mm bore bearing on the motor shaft?

Comment: @jsotola I can't figure out how to do it. Which does not mean it's impossible, I am not a mechanical engineer

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pillow+block&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Sorry, i don't see how to use it 

Comment: You usually need 2 bearings for starters. But yes you can make the shaft longer then make a coupling piece in between that goes over both shafts.

Comment: The shaft being D shaped is of little importance if it is small enough.  Put a bearing on it.  If you need to make yourself feel better, shove some stock into the gap.  There are also couplers, collars, and various accessories that you can use to attach to the shaft.

Comment: The illustration is a big help. Is the axis of rotation horizontal, as shown, or vertical or any old way? How much more axial length can you tolerate (for bearings and coupling between the disk and the gearhead)?

Comment: @Transistor this is why i am having hard time with pictures :) The axis is straight through the motor - so horizontal for this picture. But the motor is going to be positioned vertically. So the weight of the table (up to 15kg) will be directed axially, which is why i don't trust gear/motor internal bearings. In terms of length - the less the better, but i guess 10-20mm should not be a problem. However, if i just put a coupling above the bearing, i think weight will be applied to the gear shaft again, instead of the bearing.

Comment: @TQQQ downvote for putting important description into a comment, where it is not seen by anyone reading the question ... please add info to the question, not in a comment

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lazy+susan&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: "important information" does not end there, it goes through size, production packing and sales. I wouldn't know where to stop.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments (but should be in the question!):

> The motor is going to be positioned vertically. So the weight of the table (up to 15kg) will be directed axially, which is why i don't trust gear/motor internal bearings.

You are right to be concerned. You need a vertical pillow bearing to take the weight and possibly a second bearing to ensure shaft alignment. See [vertical+pillow+block+bearing](https://www.google.com/search?q=vertical+pillow+block+bearing) image search.

Then you need a [flexible shaft coupling](https://www.google.com/search?q=flexible+shaft+coupling) to cater for any axis misalignment and to ensure that no vertical load is applied to the gearbox. In your case you want one that you can drill out to 9 mm on one end and 8 mm on the other. A clamp ring will grip the D-shaft adequately but you could use a grub screw if you wish.

---

Update regarding your proposal:

[image]

*Figure 1. Gearbox mounting, standoffs and bearing support.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Cross-section view.*

Instead of two standoffs, turn a hollow cylinder to go from the gearbox plate to the bearing support (and make the bearing sit into the top). Add a pair of slots to allow access to the coupling clamping screws.

[image]

*Figure 3. A star coupling. Image source: [Miki Pulley](https://www.mikipulley.in/star-coupling.html).*

Another possibility is a star coupling. This allows for some misalignment of the two axes, provides some vibration absorbtion and has the advantage that the stars can be tightened on each component before assembly. During assembly the star is inserted, the shafts aligned and the two halves engaged.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, but I still don't understand what to do about the pillow bearing

Comment: Have a look at 2:45 on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q25EUszBSI.

Comment: OK, so this part i did know. Overall, correct me i am wrong, you propose to fix the bearing in some way to hold the weight, have the table shaft go through the bore down, then have a shaft coupling fixed on it and the motor. I will try to model it, but it seems i will not have a good access to the coupling between the bearing and the gear, if any

Comment: Yes, the bearing can just sit in a counterbore hole or pocket so that it's supported underneath. You really need a second bearing to keep it straight.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much

Comment: Ideally make the table shaft diameter larger above the bearing so that it just drops in and stops on the inner ring.

Comment: Yes, that part I understand. Problem now is in mounting the motor with the coupling. All becomes very small, not good for assembly by customer. But maybe I'll figure it out later. Thank you!

Comment: So i get this thing now:
 https://imgur.com/a/ebWs2MI   
https://imgur.com/a/yl5rcaM

There is a space to insert a very small 8mm to 8mm coupling (16mm diameter). However now, because i need to insert the coupling, the whole 15kg will stand on two aluminum posts which don't look very reliable honestly.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Should I do the D for the other shaft too?

Comment: It depends on the  clamp. I probably wouldn't.

Comment: And so this is what i get. Assuming Chinese have the right coupling, which they should. 

https://imgur.com/a/4RyVVLo

What do you think?

Comment: It looks professional.

Comment: Yeah, it's not me, it's the CAD   thank you